# Post request works but response (on code 200) is not returned. React

Tags: reactjs, axios

Post request works but response (on code 200) is not returned.

```
`axios
 .post(url, JSON.stringify(data))
 .then((resp) => {
 console.log("resp: ", resp.data.body);
 console.log("result: ", resp.data.result);
 alert(Success ${JSON.stringify(resp.data.result)});
 })
.catch((err) => {console.error("Problem with Add: ", err); }); };`
```

When running the same request in postman i get the response with custom error:

```
`{
"statusCode": 200,
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "",
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "",
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
},
```

"body": ""Success"",
"result": [
{
"@full_error": "ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '501151' for key 'PRIMARY'"
}]}`

Please advise

Comment: are you sure that in the console you do not have a error? looks to me that the request goes into the then and you access resp.data.result which is not defined

Comment: it does not even get to "console".